# In a Drupal environment: is there a better git deployment than my current one?

Tags: git, deployment

We're running a middle-big website with Drupal and maintain code with git. Recently, we also began to deploy live using git (formerly we just used git to better maintain and backup code).

Unfortunately our git folder structure is as follows:

- all < *the folder that is necessary for the actual deployment*
- sql < *sql dumps for local testing, not needed for deployment*
- public < *the folder where all the website's images are put, not needed for deployment*

Unfortunate because these folders are not on one layer in the live environment (while sql and public shouldnt even be pushed online anyways).

So what we did is create another folder called workspace where git checks out to after a push is received and copies only the relevant *all* folder into the live project folder, in `hooks/post-receive`:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=~/workspace/live git checkout -f master

# remove the current all folder to actually delete deleted files
rm -rf ~/www.website.com/sites/all
cp -r ~/workspace/live/all ~/www.website.com/sites/.
```

We just wondered if there are any downsides to that or if there even is a better way of doing it?

It works well, but you never know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible drawback is in term of:

- transition (it is best to gracefully stop the server while transitioning the site, which is here done with a cp)
- rollback: if you need to quickly site on the previous version of the site because of some snafu, you need to push again, and wait for a new `cp` to complete.

It would be better to:

- checkout as you do, but in a dedicated folder named after the revision you are checkouting,
- gracefully stop the web server
- change the link from ~/www.website.com/sites/all to that new folder
- restart the server

The link part is instantaneous.
And the rollback is simply changing the symlink back to its original value.

Comment: how do you gracefully stop the server? :) it can happen that even the shop is being used at the time of deployment

Comment: @Alex maybe in the case of Drupal you don't need to stop it, but the point remains: changing a symlink provides a faster transition and offer a fasterrollback than a possible lengthy `cp`.

Comment: it really sounds like a good idea indeed. i just wonder, do you have to "refresh" due to the fact that the file system/ symlink has changed? restarting sounds like a longer procedure

Comment: @Alex I have done it in the past for website served by apache (no refresh needed), not Drupal, so I don't know if there is a cache specific to Drupal that would need to be updated or reset.

Comment: Well Drupal has its own cache directories lying on different paths, I was rather thinking about php/ apache. I will give it a try. Thanks for your input!